# ExoPlayer useArtwork never being called, Thumbnail not shown

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to load a thumbnail but the video becomes enabled and `setDrawableArtwork(defaultArtwork)` is never called.

I am setting defaultArtwork with

```
public void setDefaultArtwork(@Nullable Drawable defaultArtwork) {
    if (this.defaultArtwork != defaultArtwork) {
      this.defaultArtwork = defaultArtwork;
      updateForCurrentTrackSelections(/* isNewPlayer= */ false);
    }
}
```

But when this selections for loop runs the render type is `TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO`. And the artwork is never shown.

`useArtwork` is true.

```
TrackSelectionArray selections = player.getCurrentTrackSelections();
for (int i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
  if (player.getRendererType(i) == C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO && selections.get(i) != null) {
    // Video enabled so artwork must be hidden. If the shutter is closed, it will be opened in
    // onRenderedFirstFrame().
    hideArtwork();
    return;
  }
}

// Video disabled so the shutter must be closed.
closeShutter();
// Display artwork if enabled and available, else hide it.
if (useArtwork) {
  for (int i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    TrackSelection selection = selections.get(i);
    if (selection != null) {
      for (int j = 0; j < selection.length(); j++) {
        Metadata metadata = selection.getFormat(j).metadata;
        if (metadata != null && setArtworkFromMetadata(metadata)) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (setDrawableArtwork(defaultArtwork)) {
    return;
  }
}
```

ExoPlayer : `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.0'`

Are there any ExoPlayer experts out there who can help me?

Edit :

In the meantime im probably just going to build a ImageView over PlayerView to handle thumbnails.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4639

Comment: Almost three years later I'm facing exactly the same problem and after a lot of debugging, I'm simply thinking it doesn't work :/ Would love to be wrong and that someone posts a working solution